# How to use random zoom in keras tensorflow 2.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to add random zoom to my images that are tiff files with 128x160 resolution 1 channel but new version of random zoom for keras tensorflow has gotten me confused, i don't understand how should be the tuple format it expects as the zoom range arguement.

From the documentation.

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(
    x, zoom_range, row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=0, fill_mode='nearest',
    cval=0.0, interpolation_order=1
)
```

I need to add some random zoom to my image, and i am trying like this:

```
zoom_range = ((0.4, 0.4))
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(
    img, zoom_range, row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=0, fill_mode='nearest',
    cval=0.0, interpolation_order=1
)
```

The output is:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
> 'NoneType'

How exactly should i pass as parameter any random zoom amount to my images?

Public kaggle notebook here:

https://www.kaggle.com/puelon/notebook75c416766a

TypeError: in user code:

```
    <ipython-input-4-9ba0455797a4>:17 load  *
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(img, zoom_range, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='nearest')
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:153 random_zoom  *
        x = apply_affine_transform(x, zx=zx, zy=zy, channel_axis=channel_axis,
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:321 apply_affine_transform  *
        transform_matrix = transform_matrix_offset_center(
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:246 transform_matrix_offset_center  *
        o_x = float(x) / 2 + 0.5
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/py_builtins.py:195 float_  **
        return _py_float(x)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/py_builtins.py:206 _py_float
        return float(x)
    
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneTyp

e'

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9ba0455797a4> in <module>
     27     train1, train2, test1 = d
     28     train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train1 + train2).\
---> 29         shuffle(len(train1) + len(train2)).map(load).batch(4)
     30     test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test1).\
     31         shuffle(len(test1)).map(load).batch(4)



for i in range(len(groups)):
    d = deque(groups)
    d.rotate(i)
    train1, train2, test1 = d
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train1 + train2).\
        shuffle(len(train1) + len(train2)).map(load).batch(4)
    test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test1).\
        shuffle(len(test1)).map(load).batch(4)
```

Comment: Can you provide full exception stack? Not just last message line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your `img` is of wrong object type. For `random_zoom(...)` function you need to provide input as tensor or 3D `numpy` array of shape `(height, width, channels)` i.e. for RGB image of size 300x200 array should be of shape (200, 300, 3). This kind of numpy array can be obtained for example by [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library like in code below.

Also if you're having TF code then you're dealing with tensors, but `random_zoom` needs to know all dimensions, their integer sizes. Tensors may have `None` size for some dimensions if it is unknown at graph construction time, and probably this is causing the error about `NoneType` in your case. To overcome this you need to wrap `random_zoom` usage into [numpy function interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function), this will force function input to be numpy array instead of tensor and numpy arrays always have all dimensions with known sizes. I've implemented this wrapping in my code down below too.

Also you probably need to change `row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=0` to `row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2` because channels (colors) go usually in least significant dimension (last).

Documentation for [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/random_zoom).

I've implemented simple code next that works.

Input in code looks like this:

[image: input]

output looks like this:

[image: input]

Next code can be also [run here online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64025732#main.py).

```
# Needs: python -m pip install tensorflow numpy pillow requests
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, PIL.Image, requests, io

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

zoom_range = (0.4, 0.5)

img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc3Jb.png').content))
#img = PIL.Image.open('Ruler-Big-Icon-PNG.png')
img = np.array(img)

img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img) # This line is not needed if you already have a tensor.

# You need only this single line of code to fix your issue!
img = tf.numpy_function(lambda img: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(
    img, zoom_range, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='nearest',
), [img], tf.float32)

img = np.array(img) # This line is not needed if you plan img to be a tensor futher

# Example output is https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWk9T.png
PIL.Image.fromarray(img).save('result.png')
```

Comment: @JohnJones I think I know the reason. Most TF/Keras functions have so-called batch axis at position 0 and batch axis usually has size None which is shown in exception. So you need this fix `row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=3`.

Comment: @JohnJones I've just read doc for random_zoom, and unfortunately you must take into account that it only supports 3D input tensor. It means that you can't process batches. So if you have 4D output of previous operations then you have to loop. But wait, I have very slow internet here (dozens KBs per sec) and need a lot of time. Maybe you have 3D tensor, but widht or height dimension is unknown there, i.e. is None.

Comment: @JohnJones If some of dimensions are unknown and None like in your case you need to wrap random_zoom line in kaggle into [numpy function wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function), this will make all dimensions known. Terrible slow internet, waiting to load.

Comment: @JohnJones I've put `numpy_function` wrapper into code of my answer, also added second paragraph regarding this, you may try doing it (wrapping).

Comment: At first it wasn't working, then i refreshed the page and saw your edit, works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnJones So `numpy_function`-solution solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, when i called the function like this: img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img), where function was defined def np_random_zoom(img):
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(
        img, zoom_range, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='nearest',
    ). Errors were gone

Comment: @JohnJones Cool! BTW, you just need one line `img = tf.numpy_function(lambda img: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(
    img, zoom_range, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='nearest',
), [img], tf.float32)`   (see current edited code). No need for doing `img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)`.

Comment: I tried this as part of tf.data.Dataset but unfortunately get "OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature."

Comment: Adding: it seemed like it didn't like me outputing the zx, zy from the picked zoom transform to outside the python func so that i use it to perform corresponding transform on landmark labels. This seemed tricky and go further than this Q, maybe will ask separately.

Comment: @kawingkelvin Maybe with updated new version of tensorflow or keras my code stopped working. But at the time when I posted my answer everything worked correctly. Zoomed images that you see in my post are made by this working code. Anyway to fix your problem we need a minimal reproducible example of your non-working code with some sample data. Also see this [run-online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64025732#main.py) link in my post, you may try running my code there, it still works correctly and produces output `result.png` file.

Comment: @Arty I sort of decided not to use numpy func for now, and instead use existing tf image API such as sample_distorted_bounding_box and pad_to_bounding_box where specific config r effectively random_zoom.

Comment: Adding, using elemental tf image API, I have more flexibility that the “zoom” doesn’t always have to be centered (doing a translate + zoom, in one op, that is).

Comment: Isn't it amazing that tf.keras.preprocessing doesn't support tf.Tensors?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm generally not convinced that using Keras preprocessing functions outside of where they belong is the right approach. A simple way would be to use `tf.image.random_crop`. Assuming your image is larger than `(200, 200, 3)`, you can just use this line:

```
img = tf.image.random_crop(img, (200, 200, 3))
```

Let's try an example. Original image:
[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import skimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.stack([skimage.data.chelsea() for _ in range(10)])

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X).\
    map(lambda x: tf.image.random_crop(x, (200, 200, 3)))

plt.imshow(next(iter(ds)))
plt.show()
```

Randomly cropped image of size `(200, 200, 3)`:
[image]

Comment: Maybe just this case can be replaced by crop but I think in general it is alright to mix code of different libraries, add some tiny adaptors. keras is a huge cool library and has many functions that where not back ported into TFs backend functions, like this random_zoom, and probably most will not be ported at all. Hence it is good to know how to make necessary wrapper from one lib to another. If you look at my current answer's code my adapter is just one-liner, so probably good enough. But thanks for you version of answer.

Comment: I disagree, you shouldn't use high level modules for such simple operations. It's best illustrated by the complex workaround you had to come up with, along with the drawbacks of `tf.numpy_function`. It's also 2x slower, and comes with [restrictions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function). It's just not made for being used like that.